# Laravel sub action controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an admin section and I want to keep urls looking nice but more importantly my code well structured.

I currently have a URL like this

```
/admin/
```

which works fine. Another URL like this

```
/admin/users
```

which also works fine

However what I now want is an admin page to add a new user which would have the url

```
/admin/users/add
```

I cannot seem to get anything to change with that URL, it always triggers the `admin/users` controllers.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: show your route file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up a route for this? Controllers by their nature allow you

```
{Controller Name} / {Controller Action}
```

To set this up the way you want them you will need to use a route

```
Route::get('admin/users/add', 'admin@user_add');
```

This will route all requests to 'admin/users/add' to the admin controller using the method 'get_user_add' or 'action_user_add' depending on whether the controller is restful.

Comment: It is advisable not to use Cotroller detect in laravel as it is buggy.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant? assuming the OP has already `Route::controller(array('admin');` previously